# Macbook Pro late 2011 screen brightness issue

Tags: 12.10, screen, brightness, macbook

The keys to set the screen brightness work properly but everytime I **reboot**, the **screen brightness is reverted to 100%**, which is very annoying.

I've already tried to add the following lines to /etc/rc.local but with no success (only the keyboard backlight stays off):

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

echo '1' > /sys/devices/platform/applesmc.768/leds/smc::kbd_backlight/brightness

echo '6' > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness

rfkill block bluetooth

exit 0`
```

This worked for me when I was using Ubuntu 12.04 and also did after the upgrade to 12.10 but then after rebooting the screen brightness always reverted to 100%.
Would be nice if anyone knows how to fix this.

My device: **Macbook Pro 13" Late 2011**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Please do double check to see if that directory exists.
You can do so by repeatedly going deeper into the directory using `cd` and `ls`.
For instance, `cd /sys` would get you into the `/sys` directory and `ls` would list whatever is in it.
For me, the above mentioned brightness controls are in `/sys/class/backlight/apple_backlight/brightness`, so in my case, its `echo '5' > /sys/class/backlight/apple_backlight/brightness`

Answer (score 0):

This is more for the sake of others reading this question because I can see how old your question is. I was able to get the set screen brightness to work by setting the values of both /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness and /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness.

I was trying to set both of them individually to see if one worked, I'm pretty sure just setting acpi_video0/brightness used to work before 13.04 but since I've updated I've been having trouble.

I would think that both values need to be the same so make sure to check the values you want are correct (acpi_video0/brightness is from 0 - 15 and intel_backlight/brightness is from 0 - 1808). For the record I am running Ubuntu GNOME 13.10 on the same model of macbook pro (8,1).

So for me I have it booting with a brightness of 3 so acpi_video0/brightness has a value of 3 and intel_backlight/brightness has a value of 357. Just set the screen to the brightness you want and check the intel_backlight/brightness to find the value you need to use.